# How to create a data frame from a list based on list specific criteria

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have the following list:

```
['1',
 'William Dunn Moseley',
 'June 25, 1845–October 1, 1849(term limited)',
 'Democratic',
 '1845',
 'Office did not exist',
 '2',
 'Thomas Brown',
 'October 1, 1849–October 3, 1853(term limited)',
 'Whig',
 '1849',
 '3',
 'James E. Broome',
 'October 3, 1853–October 5, 1857(term limited)',
 'Democratic',
 '1853',
]
```

Each number in the list corresponds to a row in dataset I want to generate. Therefore, from this list, id like to generate a dataset that looks something like the below:

```
Number         Name                            Term                              Party       Election       Office
1      'William Dunn Moseley' 'June 25, 1845–October 1, 1849(term limited)'    Democratic     1845    'Office did not exist'
2          'Thomas Brown'     'October 1, 1849–October 3, 1853(term limited)'    'Whig'      '1849'    NA
3         'James E. Broome'   'October 3, 1853–October 5, 1857(term limited)'  'Democratic'  '1853'    NA
```

Is there an easy way to flip a list into a data frame based on or in between certain values, such as the row numbers, within a list?

Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated! Thanks so much.

Comment: are all the rows going to have complete data?
i.e. will there be an equal number of positions occupied by each row in the list?

Comment: All the rows will not be filled in, there will be some missing data. But the data is in order. So if the list does not have 6 elements per row, the missing data will be at the end of the dataset (i.e. in the "office" column).

Comment: The main problem of your example list is that exactly what @Usernamenotfound asked is not the case. The first sequence explicitely contains `Office did not exist` as entry for the office column, while this entry simply lacks in the other two sequences. Can you prevent that? Otherwise it would have to be a much more complicated, less general solution which explicitely looks for this issue...

Comment: Gotcha, I understand. Unfortunately, this problem cannot be prevented in the data that I am working with. But I'll change it in the example, as it would be useful to know how it is done.

Comment: If it's not possible to change, you shouldn't change the example... Is the entry always either `Office did not exist` or not existent?

Comment: Alright, that sounds good as well. The entry is either a string or it is non-existent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be hard to do it with 100% precision because your data is irregular, but here's something.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

number_of_presidents = 3

presidents = np.array(['1',
 'William Dunn Moseley', 'June 25, 1845–October 1, 1849(term limited)',
 'Democratic', '1845',  'Office did not exist',  '2', 'Thomas Brown',
 'October 1, 1849–October 3, 1853(term limited)', 'Whig', '1849',
 '3', 'James E. Broome', 'October 3, 1853–October 5, 1857(term limited)',
 'Democratic', '1853'])

indexes = []

for i in range(1, number_of_presidents + 1):
    indexes.append(np.where(presidents == str(i))[0][0])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.split(presidents, indexes)[1:]).iloc[:, 1:]

print(df)
```

> ```
>     1  ...                     5
> ```
>
> 0  William Dunn Moseley  ...  Office did not exist
>
> 1          Thomas Brown  ...                  None
>
> 2       James E. Broome  ...                  None
>
> [3 rows x 5 columns]

Answer (score 0):

storing your list in `L` you could do it as follows:

First, correct the list.
Check every 6th element if it's a number and insert an empty string element if yes. If after this loop the length of the list is a multiple of 6 it's already finished,  otherwise append another empty string:

```
i = 5
while i < len(L):
    if L[i].isdecimal():
        L.insert(i, '')
    i += 6
if len(L)%6 != 0:
    L.append('')
```

With this regular list the creation of a dataframe is easy, just transform the list into 2D i.e. a list of sublists and add the column names:

```
import pandas as pd

values = [L[i:i+6] for i in range(0, len(L), 6)]
col = ['Number', 'Name', 'Term', 'Party', 'Election', 'Office']

df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=col)

#   Number                  Name  ... Election                Office
# 0      1  William Dunn Moseley  ...     1845  Office did not exist                                
# 1      2          Thomas Brown  ...     1849                                                          
# 2      3       James E. Broome  ...     1853
```

Answer (score 0):

It **doesn't matter** if the last two presidents don't have 'Office did not exist'. And you don't need to know how many presidents there are. ;D

You could simply loop over and break them into rows when you encounter the index

```
temp = []
output = []
idx = 0

for row in a:
    if row.isnumeric() and int(row) == idx+1:
        output.append(temp)
        temp = []
        idx += 1
        continue
    temp.append(row)

output.append(temp)
df = pandas.DataFrame(output[1:], columns=column_names)
```

This would give you what you want. But you have to label the column names.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by looping through your array incrementing the value of i by the number of columns you have and holding the data in a dictionary, for instance :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktFg5.png)